# Can't Extend Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this stupid simple date extension, and I am not sure why it does not work:

```
function ToShortDateString(){
  var cur_date = this;
  if(!cur_date instanceof Date){
    return 'Not A Date';
  }
  if(Date.parse('2/6/2009')=== 1233896400000){
    return [cur_date.getMonth()+1, cur_date.getDate(), cur_date.getFullYear()].join('/');
  }
  return [cur_date.getDate(), cur_date.getMonth()+1, cur_date.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
Date.prototype.toShortDateString = ToShortDateString;
```

when I do the following though, it blows up:

```
var myDate = Date();
var myString = myDate.toShortDateString();
```

Why is my prototype extension not being added to new Date objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you are calling the Date constructor. Date requires the new operator. Currently you are storing a string in myDate

```
var mydate = Date(); // string
var otherDate = new Date(); // Date
```

More succinctly

```
Date() instanceof Date // false
new Date() instanceof Date // true
```

Comment: @NathanTregillus It happens to the best of us. JS type system has been broken for decades.

Comment: aaand. you answered to fast. have to wait 6 more minutes